# NDK causes error while building

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I tried to add Android native library to my project in Eclipse, the problem is that I got this error while building:

```
.../stdio/fmemopen.c:209:38: error: '__sflags' was not declared in this scope
```

I've found that the __sflags is declared in

```
 /ndk/sources/android/libportable/arch-mips/flags.c
```

How could I make it work?